# Is allOf cannot be used in RAML 0.8?

Tags: jsonschema, raml

In my Scraml project, Am using a JSON schema like this.

```
{
   "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
   "id": "file:///C:/json",
   "DomainResource": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "Some"
        },
        {...}
        ]
    }, 
    properties : {
    }
}
```

But allOf, doesnt gives any error. And the RAML doesnt recognises it. The result from scraml also doesnt have the sub-schema in the generated case classes.

How to use allOf, in RAML 0.8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem seems to be specific to Scraml. Maybe it is better to create a github issue for them.